# No birth certificate to exit Russia

Tags: passports, paperwork, russia, russian-citizens

My mother and I have different surnames so immigration officers often ask for a birth certificate.

Today I applied for my [Internal Passport Of Russia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_passport_of_Russia). To apply, I had to hand in my birth certificate. The application takes 10 working days or less, but I leave the country in around 7/8 working days.

I am worried the application couldn’t be completed in time. This isn’t a problem as the passport can be held for a year, before my next visit. But the issue is, I won’t be able to leave the country if my passport isn’t ready as I can’t collect my birth certificate.

What can be done in this case?

Comment: Daniil, is it to prove you are the son of your mother? If so, any form she has to prove that might be enough.

Comment: @Willeke yes it is as we have different surnames. Unsure if we are allowed to exit with no proof

Comment: The Wikipedia page you cite contains this text: _Internal Russian passports are issued only inside the country. Russian citizens who live abroad can get internal passport only if they visit Russia, i.e., it is not possible to get internal passport in the Russian consulate abroad. In practice, Russian citizens who live abroad often do not get new internal passports at all, as the law allows them to prove their identity with an international Russian passport (travel document)._ Sounds like you may use your International Russian Passport to prove your identity and pass Russia's exit immigration.

Comment: @David, it seems that the problem is not to show a passport but to prove that Daniil is traveling with his mother and as such not being abducted or running away. With different names, having proof of the relationship is more important.

Comment: @Daniil Might you be able to get another copy of your birth certificate before you're scheduled to leave?

Comment: This is a good idea. I've had two official copies of my birth certificate for over a decade. It occasionally comes in handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a new birth certificate just in case but I was able to call the passport office and they were happy to prioritise my application. Now, my Internal Passport acts as my birth certificate and I can leave the country.